# How can we make use of Selenium WebDriver and Appium in the same scenario implemented using Cucumber?

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I have a situation where I need to perform some steps in the Website(Selenium) where I execute some steps to create some data and them it is pushed to mobile app. I want to work on it on the Mobile side(Appium) and take the flow ahead. Once I complete the operations on mobile. I must validate the same on Web site again.
This all needs to be done in one scenario as I don't want my scenarios to be dependent on other scenario.
Basically the web flow will be present in every scenario I would be writing.

Now when I am trying to do this using Background or `@Before`, Even my *Appium* object is instantiated and remains idle till the time *WebDriver* performs its steps. I want my *AppiumDriver* to be instantiated only after the execution of *WebDriver* Steps. I appreciate your help. TIA!

Answer (score 0):

background once in a feature before any scenario  on that feature.

before executes each time before any scenario.

As per your requirement it depends when you are initializing your AppiumDriver instance, It means if your  initializing your appium driver in a gherkin statement then using before can work for you, use

Tagged Hooks
It is possible to define a hook so that it is only executed before or after scenarios that are tagged with a specified annotation, for example:

```
Feature: web text munger kata
  @web
  Scenario: It should process a sentence
```

Tag your scenario which required this before to run only for it, not for all

Stepsdefination:

```
@Before("@web")
public void beforeScenario() {
  // perform your webdriver code
}
```

For better understanding go through the below link:

https://zsoltfabok.com/blog/2012/09/cucumber-jvm-hooks/